# how to change model fields value in CreateView

Tags: python, django

I currently have the following in my `CreateView`:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ["title", "content", "quiet_tag", "camera_tag"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        user = self.request.user.profile
        print("hello")
        # print(form.instance.title) <--- what I want to pass into user.participating_in
        # user.participating_in = Post(form.instance.title) <--- where I'm stuck
        print(user.participating_in) <--- returns nothing even though form.instance.title gives me the correct title
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In my models I have the following

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participating_in = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{ self.user }'s Profile"
```

When the user is created they automatically get a profile and their `participating_in` field is set to null. When the user makes a post I want `participating_in` to be set to the title of the post they're making but I can't seem to figure out how to change the value for `participating_in` inside of `PostCreateView`.

Comment: IMHO, your models are very inconvenient to work with. You will have trouble working with them. I would exclude participating_in from the Profile model, and I would add user as a foreign key to Post model. In this case I would be able to track all user posts with: some_user.post_set.all()

Comment: You could use a pre_save signals to do that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions